# Update status function in PHP not working properly

Tags: php, sql-update

I wrote a update function when user logins and logouts, the code is

```
function update_status_offline($id) {
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE id = $id"); }
```

And the same for online status,  everything works great but when I removed

`header('Location: ../');`

It show me following error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for update_status_offline() (...)

What could be wrong in the code ?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained and the deprecation process has begun, see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql-connect). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli); [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the argument to the function

If you have:

```
update_status_offline();
```

it needs to be changed to:

```
update_status_offline($id);
```

or alternatively remove `$id` from the function as it seems it is already being set.

```
function update_status_offline(){
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE id = $id"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (no arg)

```
function update_status_offline()
{
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET status = 0 WHERE id = $id"); 
}
```